# Autoscale DICOM images in "implay"

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a series of DICOM files that I'm displaying through implay but I'm not sure how to use the autoscaling syntax so the video doesn't look all whitewashed. Usually with imshow or imtool its "imtool(I,'DisplayRange',[])" but how can I do the same to implay?

```
D = dir('*.dcm');
baseFilenames = {D.name};
numberOfFiles = length(baseFilenames);
for k = 1:numberOfFiles
    fullFileName = baseFilenames{k};
    imArray(:,:,k) = dicomread(fullFileName);
end
implay(imArray)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an autoscaler for `implay`.

If your data is type double, you should scale it manually so your images are between [0 1] - that is what is expected by most Image Processing toolbox functions. There are various functions like `imadjust` that could be used for this purpose but chances are that you can simply apply the same factor to the entire image stack. If you don't actually want to modify `imArray` because you need the original DICOM values for later, you can just do it in the `implay` line:

```
implay(imArray./sf)
```

(Will get slightly more complex if you have negative values in your DICOM, of course).

Comment: I do need to use the DICOM values later so I tried the "./sf" but I get this error: Error using stateflow\private\sflibrary
Too many output arguments.

Comment: You need to define an actual scaling factor - that's just a placeholder I put in because I don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to find out what scaling factor the autoscaler uses?